# How to create a map with 2 key value

Tags: c++

I am looking for something like a school time table. Based on two input - Day of the week and Time of the day, one decides the subject. To implement this in c++, I was thinking of something like "map < pair < int, int>, int>". 
I was reading [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/62216-stl-map-two-keys) to use a key class and operator overloading.
Is there any other elegant way of doing it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does the "key class" offer that `std::pair` does not?

Comment: if it's a homework, please tag it. in this case you'll receive appropriate answers that doesn't involve 3pr-party libraries

Comment: @AndyT its not a homework. I was looking for some best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a map with two keys (which would allow you to look up items from knowledge of just one key), it's a composite key, and `map<pair<day, time>, subject>` should work just fine.

Also consider `map<day, map<time, subject>>`.

Comment: +1 for the last recommendation, it sounds like correct one because most probably `time` depends on `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You could typedef it.

```
typedef pair<int, int> key;
map<key, int> myMap = new map<key, int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a map with 2 key values, you can create a map with a complex key value (composed of two types). However, this won't let you look at the map for say just day of week regardless of time of day. I would create a new class to use as key, and some helper functions to be able to work by just day or just time.

Also, for your use case `Boost.MultiIndex` may help you.

Comment: Seems like `time` depends on `day`. In this case indexing on just `time` has no sense. So `map<date, map<time, subject> >` proposed by @Ben Voigt sounds like correct answer.

Comment: @Andy T: Why so? I would expect to be able to search on a schedule all the activities for this Monday, as well as all the activities for say 8pm this week.

Comment: Sorry. Actually I just mentioned school time table as example. I actually did not get the word complex key/composite key. So to make it clear, I had used the example. Thanks

Comment: Agreed in general, but I have a feel that it's a homework, that leads to simpler requirements and simpler solutions. Yeah, it's just my hypothesis.

Comment: I cannot use boost library as im working on an embedded project. I had been reading about the pros and cons of using boost for embedded system. I am still confused whether or not to use STL containers for my project(read the relevant posts of STL containers and embedded systems).