# How to implement a map with 2 independent keys?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a problem which is about creating a map with 2 different keys. The keys would possibly be of the same type though. The question is similar to this,

[How to create a map with 2 key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921863/how-to-create-a-map-with-2-key-value)

But it does also differ since the keys does not need to be set at the same time. So more concretely, the properties should be that,

1) One of the keys are sufficient to get a value from the map.

2) In case one of the keys are set, the other key can be set given the first key.

3) The user should not need to bother what key it uses (the first or the second)

The theory is to implement this using 2 maps as this,

```
public MultiKeyMap<K1, K2, V> {

private HashMap<K1 , V> map1;
private HashMap<K2, V> map2;

public MultiKeyMap(){
    map1 = new HashMap<K1, V>();
    map2 = new HashMap<K2, V>();
}

public void put(K1 k1, V v){
        ?
}

public void get(K1 k1, V v){
        ?
}

public void put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v){
    map1.put(k1, v);
    map2.put(k2, v);
}
```

However, when I get to the part with one value I get confused, The keys may both be of the same type (eg. String), so how would I make a difference between the values. One alternative would be, that in case the second value is of the same type as the first, then I just add it to the first map using duplicate values. Would this be a good option? My point is, this would affect the syntax since the user would still just call `myMap.get(myKey)`, further, I would also guess this would be an optimization since I only need one map. I would just need a flag like `boolean secondKeyAvail = false`. I should be able to handle (2) by myself. This is more to give context and motivate why this question is not the same as the linked one.

**EDIT:**

Due to some of the comments I will try to clarify a bit. This is the scenario.
Before I need to read the map I will encounter one of keys (always the same one). However, this key object may sometimes not be accessible at the time I need to read the map. I will then have a default value which is not added to the map. However, in this case I will have the second key, and if this happen I would have been able to set the second key using the first key. However, if the key is of the same type I will not know if I have the K1 key or the K2 key with the call (myMap.get(myKey)).

Comment: why not use it Map <k1, Map <k2, V>> ? If you don't have second level key then put the value with a constant / dummy key !

Comment: @StackFlowed The point is that I may have 2 different types, but not necessarily. Further, your suggestion gives me trouble accessing the second keylevel without k1. The thing is that I do often have access to one of the keys and the value and if not I can access the other key.

Comment: If you don't have first level key then use a dummy / constant for that first level key and put value in the second key val pair. I don't understand about the type thing you mentioned ...

Comment: `put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v)` when you have this put method then what is the need of `put(K1 k1, V v)`. How do you determine which map it should insert the pair?

Comment: There's a bug in your specs: suppose you had two entries, where one had a first key "foo" and the other had "foo" for the second key. What would `get("foo")` return?

Comment: You might want to check: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table

Comment: You need to restrict your types.  Either the keys can be the same or they must be different.  The problem as stated has too many issues to create a solution.

Comment: @StackFlowed The thing is that when I use the map, then I may have access to one key or another. So as soon as the second key appears I need to add it to the map. So the keys just appear in different order depending on the case. I will thus have to check on both ones when I use the map.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In that case the key would already exist. This should just skip adding the key.

Comment: Can't you reserve a single bit in the key that tells its type and work with a single map ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust This will not work if the keys are of different type. However, I would actually not need to bother whether the key is K1 or K2 in case the type is the same. So in this case I would just be able to find the "first" key in the map and add a duplicate value with a different key (so to say, the other map will not have to be used and in the 3 arg put I should be able to cast K2 to K1 in case the type is the same). Would this work you think or may I get obscure bugs?

Comment: Can't follow your explanations, sorry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Don't be, however, in a try to explain: In case the keys have different type (! (K1 instanceof K2) ) it is easy. I can just have two put methods and java would pick the right one all the time. Otherwise, I do not need K1 or K2 in separate maps. I would just need to find out if there is a key K1 which "equals" K2 and do something like `map1.put((K1) k2, map.valueof((K1) k2))`. So I would be able to have everything in one map and let the other map be empty and unused. Would this come back to punch me in the face you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is type safety on the keys? If you have separate `put` methods for each type, and then the types are the same, your compiler won't know which version to call. If you just use one method, you can't restrict the type to be "`K1` or `K2`". But if you were willing to have the `get` and `put` methods take an `Object` for the keys, or require the user to use the two-key `put` method, then you could just use a single backing HashMap that doesn't care what the key type is.

```
public MultiKeyMap<K1, K2, V> {

private HashMap<Object, V> map;

public MultiKeyMap(){
    map = new HashMap<Object, V>();
}

public void put(Object key, V v){
    map.put(key, v);
}

public void get(Object key, V v){
    return map.get(key);
}

public void put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v){
    if(!map.containsKey(k1) && !map.containsKey(k2)) {
        map.put(k1, v);
        map.put(k2, v);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the real [`HashMap.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) method takes an `Object` as its key, anyway.

Comment: This may do. I guess HashMap calls the equals method for this check, right? So having objects to equal each other should be good enough. So if the `Object` also is a String, the equals method for String should be called here I guess. This is typesafe enough. I would not need to force an exception at this point since an exception will be thrown right after in case I fail to find a value in the Map this works right now and this exception is the reason I have these troubles. Can you think of any cases where Java picks the wrong value from the map?

Comment: @patrik: Right, it'll use `.equals()`, so as long as you're not using types which implement hashcode and equals the wrong way, this should work fine. You won't get compiler warnings if you call `get` or `put` with the wrong type for the key value unless you use the two-key `put` method, but you will get compiler help for the returned value type.

Comment: Further, In case I would want more typesafety I would be able to add a check in `put` and `get` and throw an exception if I do not have an instance of K1 or K2. This should still be effective since I can have a simpler construction with only one map and no nested maps and such things. This would also be ways easier to debug than nested maps.

Comment: I think this answer is much better than most I have found on the internet, so I will wait with accepting this in order to give you better credit for it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @patrik: Don't concern yourself with my reputation. If this answers your question, mark it complete so other people don't think you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Following code implements API that lets you to put value either by K1 or by K2, to get value by any key and to propagate one key to another

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 

    public final X x; 
    public final Y y; 

    public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
    } 
} 

public MultiKeyMap<K1, K2, V> {

    private HashMap<Tuple<K1, K2> , V> map;

    public MultiKeyMap(){
        map = new HashMap<Tuple<K1, K2>, V>();
    }

    public void putByK1(K1 k1, V v){
        map.put(new Tuple(k1, null), v);
    }

    public void putByK2(K2 k2, V v){
        map.put(new Tuple(null, k2), v);
    }

    public void getByK1(K1 k1){
        map.get(new Tuple(k1, null));        
    }

    public void getByK2(K2 k2){
        map.get(new Tuple(null, k2));        
    }

    public void put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v){
        map.put(new Tuple(null, k2), v);
        map.put(new Tuple(k1, null), v);
    }

    public void propagateK1(K1 k1, K2 k2) {
        map.put(new Tuple(null, k2), get(k1));
    }

    public void propagateK2(K2 k2, K1 k1) {
        map.put(new Tuple(k1, null), get(k2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, specified type in API

Comment: "The user should not need to bother what key it uses (the first or the second)" -- that means you can't have separate `getByK1` and `getByK2` methods.